# Effect of IR absorption on visible region refractive index of Glass

Tags: optics, optical-materials

If we go with the Lorentz oscillator model of susceptibility, it is obvious that high frequency resonance tails raise the refractive index of low frequency light. However, I recently came across a question in a paper that asks how IR absorption in glass could affect the refractive index in the visible region. I am clueless as to how there could be a connection between the two.

Comment: But wouldn't Kramers-Kronig applied to the newly introduced IR absorption also come with dispersive effect far detuned?

Comment: Contribution from the KK integral will be minimal at frequencies larger than the resonance frequency while it would add a finite constant at lower frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise the temperature of the glass with IR and the index of refraction in the visible region is temperature dependent, this could be a connection.

Comment: Excellent point!